# SAP WEB IDE Error when building application

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

In SAP WEB IDE I'm building my project (Right-Clck + Build).
This was working correctly but now it's erroring with:

```
4​:43:07 PM (Build) Build started. 4:43:10 PM (DIBuild) Build of /rsa-complete-survey in progress 4:43:11 PM (DIBuild) [INFO] Retrieving source code

[INFO] Preparing node environment
[INFO] package.json not modified, skipping npm installation
[INFO] Using recently cached node_modules
[INFO] Node environment ready
4:43:15 PM (DIBuild) grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.2.0)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, grunt hasn't been installed locally to
your project. For more information about installing and configuring grunt,
please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
[INFO] Build finished in 4 seconds
```

Any ideas?

Comment: According to SAP, the fix is deployed now. Restart your Web IDE and try again.

Comment: Yeah, It's now sorted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should to be a temporary problem. [Others are reporting similar issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwDC6.gif) as well. To join the discussion, click [here](https://slackui5invite.herokuapp.com/) to get invited and visit the channel *#sapwebide*.